# Apollo graphql application cookie not set in browser

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, nodejs-server

I am using apollo graphql on backend side and using cookie authentication method. But when I set cookie on backend side cookie was in Set-Cookie header but doesn't showed in Browser->application ->cookies

```
response.cookie('tokens', token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true, //process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        sameSite: true,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
      });
```

Returned response:
[Response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWweN.png)

Nothing here.
[Application cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/686JY.png)

Tried many advices but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the cookie by

```
        context.setCookies.push({
          name: "token",
          value: result.token,
          options: {
              domain:'DOMAIN_NAME',
              httpOnly: true,
              maxAge: 36000,
              secure: 'none',
              path: '/',
              sameSite:'None'
          }
      });
```

- Remember to make sure domain name is your Server host name,
- no need of protocol in domain, i.e., https
- set samesite to none

by this, I was able to set the cookie and it was set in application folder in developers tool

- you cannot test this in incognito,
- in network tab, in the rest call, in cookie section, you can confirm if all attribute is set correct or not.